# make required text field on the basis of piklist field

Tags: validation-rule

I have one piklist field(Staus-Open/close/pending) and one text fields(Account).

When "status" is equal to open then "Account" required.

We want to make it with help of validation rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below one in your validation rule

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(Status,'Open'),ISBLANK(Account))
```

and give the ERROR Message like **`Account Should Not be null if the Status is Open`**

Hope this might helps...